# Cursor movement independent from mouse

Tags: java, cursor, mouse, smoothing

What  want to do, is to smooth cursor movement.

Is it possible to move mouse without directly changing cursor coordinates and then lerp it's position, to where it should be? May be there is a way to have independent coordinates for mouse and cursor?

Comment: Show your code and be precise about what your question is.

Comment: Sure. Basically I want mouse not to move cursor, and move it myself with code instead. Code [pastebin.com/mvxZn8Q1](http://pastebin.com/mvxZn8Q1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `mouseMove(int x, int y)` of the class [java.awt.Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html). The same class contains also other methods to simulate native events that could be useful.